# Cant get the picture from Firebase using Datasnapshot link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to get a picture from my Firebase and show it in the app.
every time i check the value in the link im getting through DataSnapshot it says null and wont display the image.
my code:

```
public class GuessesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    User user;
    ImageView Team1;

    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    private DatabaseReference first = databaseReference.child("gtsapp-1b4df-default-rtdb");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guesses);

        Team1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1);
        onStart();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        first.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override

            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String link = dataSnapshot.child("Logo1").getValue(String.class);
                //String link = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gtsapp-1b4df.appspot.com/o/barcelona.png?alt=media&token=78160f15-e02a-4aa1-b57e-54dc8678fde6";
                Toast.makeText(GuessesActivity.this, "link" + link, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Picasso.get().load(link).into(Team1);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: My FireBase]

Answer (score 2):

`getReference()` is referencing the root node in the database, therefore you shouldn't do:

```
private DatabaseReference first = databaseReference.child("gtsapp-1b4df-default-rtdb");
```

---

Try the following:

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Hi Peter.
it doesnt work... i dont know why.
i think there is no conection to the firebase in those code lines so it cant understand where ro rake the image from